# How open the AutoIt script from excel workbook and after that parent Workbook get close?

Tags: excel, autoit, vba

In my current project, Excel macro open AutoIt script using a function 
`Call Shell("location of autoit script")`.

For proper functioning of AutoIt script it's need to be close parent Excel workbook, so this closing Excel action is  written in AutoIt script itself.

But as soon as AutoIt script close parent Excel workbook then script get pause and it do nothing.

How open the AutoIt script from Excel workbook and after that parent Workbook get close?

Comment: I believe the issue is that if you call a script from a workbook `Call Shell("location of autoit script")`
then this script is run within the scope of the workbook which started the script. If you now close the workbook, then the script is aborted too, because its scope was closed, so the script stops immediately.

Comment: Don't know much about autoit, but try to launch a batch file from your VBA that triggers the autoit script. You might be able to get round it that way.. not tested though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can solve with open the AutoIT script first and then open Excel file using AutoIT script, after that AutoIT close itself and still Excel is open.